# Derivative of a matrix times a vector within an exponential function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Let us consider $\beta:=(\beta_1,...,\beta_p)^T$ and $X$ a matrix of dimension ($n\times p$). I would like to calculate the following derivative $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\exp(X\beta) $$

Is it possible?

Comment: how do you define $\exp(X\beta)?$

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure I understood the question

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential It only defined matrix exponential for square matrix. But here $X\beta$ is a vector, so how are you defining $\exp(X\beta)$?

Comment: @Andrew I have the following intensity function: $\alpha+\gamma U+X\beta-T\exp{(\alpha+X\beta)}\exp{(\gamma U)}$. $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are numbers, $U$ and $T$ are column vectors with size $n$, $X$ is the design matrix and $\beta$ the associated vector of coefficitens. I'm trying to find the estimator for $\beta$. I was trying to solve the score equation. But I don't know how to differentiate the exponential function above.

Comment: But the dimensions are a bit inconsistent... when you sum $alpha$ to the vectors afterwards, you mean you broadcast $\alpha$ as a vector and sum or what? Also, as previously asked, what is the definition of exponential of a vector? Are you considering element-wise exponential? Also, your function is a vector function and not a scalar function, correct?

Answer (score 0):

In my general, the derivative of an $n$-dimensonal function $\boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x)$ with $p$ variables is a $(p\times n)$ matrix $[\frac{\partial \boldsymbol f}{\partial \boldsymbol x}]_{i,j}=\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\exp(X\beta) $ can be calculated to be $X^T diag(\exp(X\beta)$.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Let's use a convention wherein an uppercase Latin letter denotes a matrix,
lowercase Latin a vector, and Greek a scalar.
Then define the following vector variables
$$\eqalign{
w &= Xb &\qiq dw = X\,db \\
f &= \exp(w) &\qiq F = \Diag f \\
}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient of the elementwise `exp()` function
$$\eqalign{
df &= f\odot dw \;=\; F\: dw \;=\; FX\,db \\
\grad fb &= FX \\
}$$
In the above, $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.
Conveniently, Hadamard multiplication by a vector can
be replaced by matrix multiplication with a diagonal matrix.